# Create a complex state machine in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a very complex state machine and I need to use the Qt framework state machine to do it. I know how to create a state using the Qt framework, but I don't know where to put the code inside each state that should occur.

I only know about `addtransition`, but where to put the code inside the switch case ?

```
switch (state) {
        case Z_START:

            state = Z_SAMPLE;
            emit stateChanged(Z_SAMPLE,0);

        case Z_SAMPLE:
        {

            DP_ANDY = false;    // moved to Z sample
            GSet.absP = Fp.pxf; //s08 //remember ambient pressure for correction // moved to Z sample

            ig.reset();

           //setSecondlineibited(true); // moved to state=Z_SAMPLE;
            int next = nextSample();
            /*
            for(;current_sample<FlashSampler;current_sample++)
            {
                currentMeasurement = SamplerTable.at(current_sample);
                if(currentMeasurement->enabled)
                    break;
            }
            */
            if(next>=FlashSampler)
            {
                htim=1;
                wtim=1;
                emit stateChanged(state = Z_FINI,resStat /*0*/);  // use state of last result instead of 0!
                break;
            }
            current_sample=next;
            currentMeasurement = SamplerTable.at(current_sample);

            precool = Ta >currentMeasurement->Ta;
#endif

            MethSet* ms = currentMeasurement->getMethod()->methset;
            Ta = currentMeasurement->Ta;//s117
            Te = currentMeasurement->Te;
            Ts = Ta - GSet.stdT;
            Ti = Ta; //wirkungslos hier
            St = ms->Step;
            Rt = ms->Rate / 200.0f;  // C/min alle 300 ms
            for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
                Ptim[i]=(int)(ms->airVol[i]*PUMPFACT);
#ifndef FlashSampler
            if(Fp.powvers<200)
                stirval = (ms->stir?255:0); //stirrer was at fixed speed for first 5 units with old powerboard
            else
#endif
                stirval=(int)((float)ms->stir/7.5f); //factor to be set
            if(stirval&&stirval<5)
                stirval=5;

state=Z_SAMPLE_wait,0);
        }
```

Comment: When using `QStateMachine` there _shouldn't be_ any switch statement. Read [the State Machine Framework documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html).

Comment: yes I know that, but where is the logic is executed ?

Comment: In slots that you connect to `QState::entered()` or `QState::exited()`. You can also use targetless transitions to effect output without changing the current state. It's all in the documentation I linked.

Comment: so I should inherit from qstate and write my own entered and write the logic there and also If I want to transit to another state I should do it inside the entered function ?